# Problems with understanding this use of lambda with max

Tags: python, lambda, max

I am currently trying to learn more about lambda functions and ran into the following string of code:

`max_val = max(list_val, key = lambda i: (isinstance(i, int), i))`

What does this part in the code actually mean/do:

`(isinstance(i, int), i)`

I do know what isinstance's purpose is but what is the second i doing here and what are the brackets around this whole thing doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function returned by the following `lambda` expression:

```
lambda i: (isinstance(i, int), i)
```

is the same as the function that is assigned to `f` by the following `def` statement:

```
def f(i):
    return (isinstance(i, int), i)
```

The return value of the function (which takes `i` as an argument) is a tuple where the first element is a `bool` indicating whether `i` is an `int`, and the second element is `i` itself:

```
>>> f(5)
(True, 5)
>>> f("foo")
(False, 'foo')
```

Tuples are compared in order of their elements, so in the context of the `max` call, this means that you'll get the largest `int` value (because `True` is "greater than" `False`), and will get the largest of whatever other type of value you have only if there are no `int` values.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. Thought it was a lambda thing but actually learned more about how max() works.

Answer (score 1):

`isinstance` is a unit test that compares two objects and sees whether they are of the same type of object. In this case it validates whether `i` is an integer, as defined by object `int`. By the looks of it this is parsed as a tuple, together with actual value. So you get a list of:
`[('isItAnInteger', 'actualValue'),etc]`
So it returns a list of tuples with a boolean telling you whether it is an integer or not, and the actual value `i`.

The weird part is the max operator. I can image that it would select all the tuples that are `isinstance=True`, meaning that they are integers. True is also represented by the number `1` and False is represented by the number `0`. Therefore, the max values should be `True`...

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Helped me understand what is going on for sure.